# Is there anyway to use relative link instead of absolute link?

Tags: links

I have working on `xx.xyz.com` then my project is move on `xyz.com`

In which I have gave in project the previous link is as below

> .xyz.com/?page_id=634

And now my link is as belows

> xyz.com/?page_id=634

I have tried to put link relative like

> ../?page_id=634

but its not working. Any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: Can you give some more details? Are you talking about theme files, plugin files or site content?

Comment: I got its  just a /?page_id=634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) ( or something similar ) in your links for theme files when linking to pages. This will allow the domain to change and not affect your hardcoded links - assuming the ID's are the same of course.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/?page_id=634">Link</a>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can you mark it answered? :)

Comment: Sure Why not :)

Comment: this apparently does solve the issue for the OP, but it is still actually an absolute link. (Just to clarify, for anyone else who might be looking for this answer.)

Comment: Agreed. However I believe that in this case he was looking for the relative path because he wasn't using the built-in WordPress methods that are made for this sort of thing. Which negates the need ( in this case anyway ) for relative urls.

Answer (score -2):

Declare first page id  `$page_id = 634;`  , because you will need it to get page url by id. You can put it directly into the method, but its better to separate it, its more neat.

Than you use ` inside of HTML href element to make a link to the page. You dont need to write absolute link, it is NOT recommended at all. When ever you can, try to avoid apsolute link/path/ etc...

```
$page_id = 634; 
<a href=" <?php get_page( $page_id ) ?> ">link text</a>
```

Comment: You should explain why this code answers the question.